# Eclipse : disabling the warning only on the folder

Tags: java, eclipse, suppress-warnings

I want to disable the little warning picture on the folder. 
But keep the warnings hint on the left in the files, they are a little disturbing.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Warnings on the folders :

[image]

Comment: The folder shows the warning sign even for a single file which has a warning. Why don't you just fix the warning ?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, there are certain files I cannot fix the warning. Berger it is not a duplication because I don't want to suppress the warning in the files that are contained in the main folder, just want the warning sign (you can see it on the screenshot I took) disappear from the folder, not the files